# Failed to select folder even though it is listed from the LIST command

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

Here's the (trimmed) output of the `LIST` command:

```
[... ((u'\\HasNoChildren', u'\\Inbox'), u'/', u'\u0412\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0449\u0438\u0435'),
     ((u'\\Noselect', u'\\HasChildren'), u'/', u'[Gmail]'),
     ((u'\\HasNoChildren', u'\\Trash'), u'/', u'[Gmail]/\u041a\u043e\u0440\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0430'),
     ((u'\\HasNoChildren', u'\\Sent'), u'/', u'[Gmail]/\u041e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435') ...]
```

And I want to select the `\Inbox` folder named `Входящие`:

```
client.select_folder(u'\u0412\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0449\u0438\u0435')
```

But I get the following error:

```
select failed: u'[NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: &BBIERQQ+BDQETwRJBDgENQ- (Failure)'
```

It says `NONEXISTENT` even though it exists and the mailbox name looks like <strike>gibberish</strike> (or encoded?) EDIT: it is the utf7 encoded string.

Note that `Входящие` is the [default name for `Inbox` for Russian accounts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/18522?hl=ru).

Selecting the other folders (`\Trash` and `\Sent`) work OK.

```
>>> client.select_folder(u'[Gmail]/\u041a\u043e\u0440\u0437\u0438\u043d\u0430')

{u'READ-WRITE': True, u'EXISTS': 115, ... }

>>> client.select_folder(u'[Gmail]/\u041e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435')

{u'READ-WRITE': True, u'EXISTS': 6013, ... }
```

---

I tried creating a folder named `ВходящиеВходящие` (I doubled it since it is a reserved/default folder name otherwise, and thus can't be used) under my own (non-Russian) account to test, and I was able to successfully select it. So I doubt the library has encoding/decoding issues:

```
>>> myaccount.select_folder(u'\u0412\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0449\u0438\u0435\u0412\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0449\u0438\u0435')

{u'READ-WRITE': True, u'EXISTS': 0, u'PERMANENTFLAGS': (u'\\Answered', u'\\Flagged', u'\\Draft', u'\\Deleted', u'\\Seen', u'$Phishing', u'1458265b0d414e28', ... }
```

*P.S. I'm using the [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) wrapper library, which handles unicode pretty well with IMAP. I've encountered other unicode folder names from other accounts before, and the library was able to select them with no problem.*

**EDIT**: Clarified some unicode string values and more code snippets

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with encoding of the text `Входящие`. When I checked their source code, I found  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` only in their `conf.py` and not in the file that actually does the decoding `imap_utf7`. Could you test the scenario with normal names for the folder?

Comment: "Could you test the scenario with normal names for the folder?" Do you mean with a non-unicode/non-modified folder name (i.e. the default of "Inbox")? Also, isn't `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` just to set the encoding of the file, and doesn't affect how the code handles unicode?

Comment: Yes, the default kinda names that are not unicode. [PEP 0263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) says, `To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must be placed into the source files...`, in which case i m guessing the file that decodes the string is not able to do it.

Comment: IMAP uses something called modified UTF-7 for folder names. Perhaps the decode and the encode did not work out the same. Can you log in with a client that does not do automatic decoding to see what the raw folder name is, and check that is what your library is indeed generating?

Comment: also, the INBOX is always named 'INBOX', so I'm a little unsure as to it can be named anything else.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the output from Google's proprietary [XLIST](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#xlist_is_deprecated) command, not LIST. XLIST is now deprecated, but it looks like IMAPCLIENT still supports it with the xlist_folders() method.

When calling XLIST, the server returns the localized name of the INBOX folder. However, per the IMAP specification (RFC 3501), the name of the INBOX folder can only be "INBOX" (case-insensitive). The localized INBOX name returned by XLIST can be displayed to the user, but the client needs to use INBOX (or inbox or InBoX) when communicating with the server.

This is also discussed in the documentation for xlist_folders() on http://imapclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.